# ISNULL and Implicit datatype conversions in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion, isnull

I came across a somewhat weird behavior with data type conversions when using ISNULL. Look at this:

```
PRINT CASE WHEN ISNULL('', 0) = 0 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END
PRINT CASE WHEN ISNULL('', 0) = '' THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END
PRINT CASE WHEN ISNULL(NULL, 0) = '' THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END
```

All of these expressions evaluate to true.
But when I declare an nvarchar variable and set it to NULL, the following happens:

```
DECLARE @charType nvarchar; SET @charType = NULL;
PRINT CASE WHEN ISNULL(@charType, 0) = '' THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END
```

This should also evaluate to true, but it evaluates to false. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `ISNULL('', 0)` returns `''` and `ISNULL(NULL, 0)` returns `0`

[**`Data Type Precedence`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) ...

> When an operator combines two expressions of different data types, the
>   rules for data type precedence specify that the data type with the
>   lower precedence is converted to the data type with the higher
>   precedence. If the conversion is not a supported implicit conversion,
>   an error is returned.

As `int` is having more `Precedence` over `char`, `''` will be converted to `int`.

```
select cast('' as int) ==> 0
```

Hence in the first case all `''` will be converted to `0`, so the query will be reduced to

```
PRINT CASE WHEN 0 = 0 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END
PRINT CASE WHEN '' = '' THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END
PRINT CASE WHEN 0 = 0 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END
```

Hence it print `true`

[**`ISNULL`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms184325.aspx) ...

> Returns the same type as check_expression. If a literal NULL is
>   provided as check_expression, returns the datatype of the
>   replacement_value. If a literal NULL is provided as check_expression
>   and no replacement_value is provided, returns an int

But in the second case as `@charType` is `null`, `ISNULL` will cast the value `0` to  `nvarchar` then the query becomes

So

```
PRINT CASE WHEN '0' = '' THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END
```

Hence it print `false`

Comment: Nicely explained. Thumbs up!

Comment: I didn't come across the explanation of ISNULL conversion behavior and this of course is the explanation - zero as replacement value is converted to '0'. That answered the question. Thanks, Praveen.

Comment: What made me post this question is the fact, that the general rule about data type precedence is not followed between check expression and replacement value in ISNULL expressions. I had a wrong assumption about that. Actually, the type of the check expression always has precedence (which is clear to me now).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
PRINT CASE WHEN CAST(ISNULL('', 0) AS nvarchar) = 0 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END
PRINT CASE WHEN CAST(ISNULL('', 0) AS nvarchar) = '' THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END
PRINT CASE WHEN CAST(ISNULL(NULL, 0) AS nvarchar) = '' THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END
```

As you can see SQL knows it needs to cast to nvarchar when @charType is set to a nvarchar type.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I came across several usages of ISNULL in existing code recently, which led me to understand fully and in-depth what's going on here. So I'm trying to achieve nothing except understand the code others wrote.